# How does one use multiple "by"s for nested descriptions?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

The software peeps at our company make these neat reports for our business peeps. For example, we might have a report called "Sales by Day":

> ## Sales by Day Report
>
> | Day | Sales |
> | --- | --- |
> | Monday | $100.00 |
> | Tuesday | $200.00 |
> | Wednesday | $450.00 |
> | Thursday | $250.00 |
> | Friday | $120.00 |

Another report may be Sales by Store (for all time):

> ## Sales by Store Report
>
> | Store | Sales |
> | --- | --- |
> | San Diego | $10,000.00 |
> | Boston | $30,000.00 |
> | Salt Lake City | $25,000.00 |
> | Gotham | $45,000.00 |

Now, if we wanted to show a breakdown per store mixed with per day, as in the following example, which title would be correct, and why?

> ## Sales by Store by Day Report *or* Sales by Day by Store Report
>
> ### San Diego
>
> | Day | Sales |
> | --- | --- |
> | Monday | $20.00 |
> | Tuesday | $25.00 |
>
> ### Boston
>
> | Day | Sales |
> | --- | --- |
> | Monday | $35.00 |
> | Tuesday | $45.00 |
>
> ....

Comment: Just to clarify: you're asking whether you work from the inside out, or from the outside in - correct?

Comment: I'd do the first, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @MT_Head yes, that's correct. I know what *I* think is right, but it's been a source of discussion lately.

Answer (score 8):

I would replace one of your *by* with *per*:

> Sales by Day per Store
>
> Sales per Day by Store

In this context *by* and *per* are effectively synonymous, so you can use either variant. However, for consistency's sake you should probably use *per* consistently in one half of the formula or the other, so that you always say (for example) *Sales Per Day*, whether or not the store breakdown is given.

Comment: I was just typing that same thing. FWIW, though, I think _Sales per Day by Store_ seems much better than the other one, based on how the report is organized.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, and one which I think I'll start using. I agree, I like _Sales perDay by Store_ better. However, if I, for whatever unholy reason, insisted on using _by_ twice, what would _Sales by Day by Store_ mean? What's the correct interpretation of that?

Answer (score 3):

First, offset the "levels" with commas or parentheses:

> Sales by Store (by Day)

or

> Sales by Store, by Day

If you are asking about the *order*, I think the correct order would be innermost to outermost grouping, but I cannot cite any authority for that, just experience.

> Sales by Day, by Store

Comment: Yes, in terms of order, "sales by day by store" is correct for this example.  For each store, you are showing their "sales by day".  Then, instead of just showing "sales by day" for a single store, you're showing "sales by day" for every store, one after the other.  So this is "sales by day by store".  Also, an alternative suggestion would be "sales by store and day".

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your two single-level examples (Sales by Day and Sales by Store), the Sales (numbers) appear on the right side, and the ordering qualifier appears to the left.  So for consistency, I think I would continue that trend.

In your final example, sales are furthest to the right, then days, then stores - so I would title the report Sales by Day, by Store.

In all fairness, however, I could probably convince myself the other way too.  As long as the labels of the qualifiers are clear, I don't think the title will lead to any confusion.

(edited to take @JeffSahol's excellent suggestion of offsetting by commas)

Answer (score 1):

Since the way you've grouped the data

It should say

> Sales by Store by Day

or even better

> Daily Sales by Store

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

I take these results are from an SQL query. You don't get to choose which way it is written, as it has to follow the sequence of grouping in the SQL query. The grouping by sales then by day gives different results than grouping first by day then by sales.